# Bind dynamically set ng-model attribute for text field

Tags: angularjs

After searching around for hours I am still unable to find an answer to my problem. I am populating a dynamic form with text fields based on values from a database, but am unable to successfully bind the fields to my model. Here's the scenario:

I've got a "project" model in my controller containing lots of project related information (name, start date, participants, category etc), but let's just focus on the "project.name" property for now. In the database I configure "forms" with a number of associated fields, where each field has a property that points to which property it corresponds to in my view model (e.g. "project.name"). At runtime I add these fields to an HTML form dynamically and attempt to set the ng-model attribute to the "modelBinding" value, in this case "project.name".

```
<div ng-repeat="formField in form.formFields">
            <input ng-model="formField.modelBinding" /></div>
```

This will result in a text box being added to my form, with ng-model="formField.modelBinding" and the textbox value = 'project.data'.

What I am trying to achieve is to set ng-model = 'project.data', in other words replace formField.modelBinding with the *value* of formField.modelBinding.

One approach that seemed logical was

```
<input ng-model = "{{formField.modelBinding}}" />
```

but this is obviously not going to work. I've tried to insert the HTML tags with ng-bind-html but this seems to only work with ng-bind, not ng-model.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can understand the issue. Could you please also share a snippet from the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to bind a value to a model from a name that you have within the `formField` you can create a directive (aka `ngModelName`) to bind your model by name from this value.

> **Observation:** My first thought was using a simple accessor like `model[formField.modelBinding]` which would simple bind the `formField.modelBinding` into a `model` member on scope. However, I didn't use the property accessor because it would create a property named by `formField.modelBinding` value and not the correct object hierarchy expected. For example, the case described on this question, `project.data` would create an object `{ 'project.data': 'my data' }` but not `{ 'project': { data: 'my data'}}` as it should.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('ngModelName', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1000,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          
          scope.$watch(attrs.ngModelName, function(ngModelName) {
                // no need to bind a model
                if (attrs.ngModel == ngModelName || !ngModelName) return;

                element.attr('ng-model', ngModelName);
                
                // remove ngModel if it's empty
                if (ngModelName == '') {
                    element.removeAttr('ng-model');
                }

                // clean the previous event handlers,
                // to rebinded on the next compile
                element.unbind();

                //recompile to apply ngModel, and rebind events
                $compile(element)(scope);
            });
          }
    };
  }])
  .controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.form = {
      formFields: [
        {
          modelBinding: 'model.project.data'
        }
      ]
    };
  
    $scope.model = {};
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="formField in form.formFields">
      <input ng-model-name="formField.modelBinding" placeholder="{{ formField.modelBinding }}" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhm, that looks like overkill. Why not jus use `[xxx]` property accessor?

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky that was my first thought as well. However, I didn't use `[xxx]` property accessor because `[xxx]` will create a property named `xxx` not the correct object hierarchy expected. For example, the case described on this question, `project.data` will create an object like `{'project.data': 'data'}` not `{project: {data: 'data'}}`, it may not be an issue, but didn't sound correct for me.

Comment: This solutions works! I made an early attempt to write a custom directive, but being new to Angular it didn't do what I hoped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the "modelBinding" attribute has the model name of the formfield, so, in that case you should do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="formField in form.formFields">
        <input ng-model="form.formFields[formField.modelBinding]" />
</div>
```

Use the modelBinding as the key to retrieve from formFields.